# My labels text wont change on loading form

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have tried to change my labels text in both the form_load and form_shown methods and nothing happens. I don't want to set the text in the properties as I want to use the text in another label later. Ive tried both these methods neither works.

```
 private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateHistoryQuestionArray();
        historyQ1.Text = historyQuestion[0];
    }
```

and

```
 private void History_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateHistoryQuestionArray();
        historyQ1.Text = historyQuestion[0];
    }
```

Comment: did u forget to link the event to the actual control?

Comment: Do the Load/Shown events definitely fire? What if you set the label text manually? `historyQ1.Text = @"Test";` What do you get for this? `MessageBox.Show(historyQuestion[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `ToString()`

```
 private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateHistoryQuestionArray();
        historyQ1.Text = historyQuestion[0].ToString();
    }
```